# Trouble converting my MySQL query to rails active record format

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following MySQL query which returns 1 column called points populated with integer values

`SELECT SUM(points) FROM (SELECT FLOOR((sum(case when correct=1 then correct else 0 end)/COUNT(*))*100) as points FROM answersheets WHERE user_id = 133 GROUP BY exercise_id, user_id) as points`

I've got it to the following point as a ruby on rails scope which is the sub query without the final sum to get a total:

`scope :base_points, ->(user_id) { select('FLOOR((SUM(case when correct=1 then correct else 0 end)/COUNT(*))*100) as points').where('user_id = ?', user_id).group(:exercise_id, :user_id) }`

But that just returns

```
 2.1.0 :073 > p = Answersheet.base_points(133)
 Answersheet Load (0.4ms)  SELECT FLOOR((SUM(case when correct=1 then correct else 0 end)/COUNT(*))*100) as points FROM `answersheets` WHERE (user_id = 133) GROUP BY exercise_id, user_id
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Answersheet id: nil>, #<Answersheet id: nil>, #<Answersheet id: nil>]>
```

What could be causing the difference between the rails console and the mysql one? My guess is bad formatting on my part

**Method based on chosen answer below**

```
def points
    query = Answersheet.select('FLOOR((SUM(case when correct=1 then correct else 0 end)/COUNT(*))*100) as points').where('user_id = ?', self.id).group(:exercise_id, :user_id)
    return query.sum(&:points)
end
```

Note: This is so I can do @user.points so I've moved the code to the user model

Comment: `.group('exercise_id', 'user_id')` perhaps? No idea on ruby, but that group by look wonky

Comment: Your sub-query looks exactly like what rails generated, did you try running the subquery in `mysql`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your scope to:

```
scope :base_points, ->(user_id) { select('FLOOR((SUM(case when correct=1 then correct else 0 end)/COUNT(*))*100) as points').where('user_id = ?', user_id).group(:exercise_id, :user_id).first[:points] }
```

I think it would be better to write this as a method though:

```
class Answersheet < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.base_points(user_id)
    scoped.select('FLOOR((SUM(case when correct=1 then correct else 0 end)/COUNT(*))*100) as points').
      where('user_id = ?', user_id).
      group(:exercise_id, :user_id).
      first[:points]
  end
```

Comment: Thank you @BroiSatse, both your answer and your feedback on the code being better as a method were correct. I've edited my question to include the method

Comment: instead of `first[:points]` you could do `.pluck(:points).first` and there won't be an Answersheet instance created for nothing.

Comment: @kimmmo - `pluck` overrides select, so it won't work.